# How to Select 'id' attribute of a <div> using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Sorry if this question is similar to some other questions already asked, but even after searching through those I have not get the expected results.

I have more than 1 div tag in my page like:

```
<div id='slider1'>&@Slider@&</div>

<div id='slider2'>&@Slider@&</div>
```

I am using jQuery to select id attribute of a div whoes value will be &@Slider@& as I need the Id for some later purpose.

I have tried using [attribute=value] selector but it isnt working as expected in this case

```
function showtext() {

    alert($("[text='slider']").prop('id'));

}
```

I will be calling this function on some event, the problem is I am getting "undefined" in the alertbox. Where am I going wrong.

Even tried using

```
function showtext() {

    alert($("[text='slider']").attr('id'));

}
```

Still getting same "undefined" result

Thank you in Advance

Comment: you should use `attr('id')`

Comment: same results my friend but thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) since you want to test the text content of a div

```
alert($("div:contains('Slider')").prop('id'));
```

---

Your selector `$("[text='slider']").prop('id')` tries to find an element with attribute `text` and value `slider`, something like `<div text="slider"></div>`

Comment: This made some change but the alert box is empty, is not containing anything

Comment: @user1933046 http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sygg7u65/1/ - can you recreate your problem using the attached fiddle

Comment: This is took  only one id. Not all id's

Comment: @RameshRajendran you need to loop and create an array - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sygg7u65/2/

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using.

```
console.log($("div:contains('Slider')").prop('id'));
```

Above code only doing first id only, if you want to get all id's, then please try below code

```
$("div:contains('Slider')").each(function() {
alert(this.id)
});
```

See this [fiddler Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/91w1zodj/)

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $( $("div:contains(Slider)") ).each(function() {
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
  });
```

Above code will return list of all matching `id` of matched `div`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **contains** to identify if a div has **Slider** text in it. I am using a javascript array to accommodate all the ids of the divs. I hope this will work-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var divs = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( $("div:contains(Slider)") ).each(function() {
  divs.push($(this).attr('id')));
  });
console.log(divs);
});
</script>
```